# HTTPS proxy with a self-signed certificate in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, proxy

I'm trying to create a HTTPS proxy server in Node.JS v0.10.24 using a self-signed certificate. Here's the code I'm using:

```
var https = require('https');

var server = https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
});

server.on('request', function(req, res) {
  res.end('hello');
});

server.listen(8080);
```

This server correctly boots up and is accessible via `https://localhost:8080`. However, when I set it as a HTTPS proxy (on Mac OS X), the server emits `connection` events but never emits either `request` or `error`, thus causing the connection to hang indefinitely and eventually time out.

Comment: What client is making the request? Is it sending a `Content-Length`? Lack of `Content-Length` means the proxy does not know when a request ends. Some, like Flash, will lie about the request's size, by setting it to something like 64K. So the server waits for all 64K even though the request is less than 2K.

Comment: Chrome, Firefox and Safari on OS X Moutain Lion.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue on my Macbook. The issue appears to be that the proxy server option in OSX is using the [HTTP CONNECT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel#HTTP_CONNECT_tunneling) method to tunnel HTTPS requests.

In short, this means that you need make your server a `http.Server` instance and handle the [connect](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_connect) event, which will involve forwarding TCP socket traffic.

I know this reply is a bit late, but I wrote my own HTTP/S proxy server that you can look at for reference: https://github.com/robu3/purokishi. The specific section covering the `connect` method is [here](https://github.com/robu3/purokishi/blob/master/lib/prokishi.js#L47-L115).